# Python 3.6 - iterating over a dictionary and then a resulting tuple to return a sum value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a simple dictionary that lists down my half yearly expenditures for seven years.

```
d = {'year1':[1,2], 'year2':[3,4], 'year3':[5,6], 'year4':[7,8], 'year5':[9,10], 'year6':[11,12], 'year7':[13,14]}
```

I would want to know how much I spent in these seven years by looping over this dictionary and printing a final sum value. Although I've been able to loop over it resulting in a tuple containing yearly sums, looping over this same, resulting tuple is giving me confusing values.

```
for key, value in d.items():
    yearly_sums = key, sum(value)
    print(yearly_sums)

    Year1 3
    Year2 7
    Year3 11
```

Till here, its good. However, when I print each `item` here for example, the loop prints 'dual' values.

```
continued from above...
for item in yearly_sums:
    print('Yearly sum is:', item)
```

I executed the above snippet to test out the print results so I could proceed with the final step and what I'm getting is:

```
Yearly sum is: Year1
Yearly sum is: 3
```

When I should be getting `Yearly sum is: 3` for `year1` as example. Now the final step that remains is to loop over these `item` and print out a final sum value but how do I clarify python that items comprise of only the numeric values and not `year1`, `year2`? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Where did January come from?

Comment: Corrected typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is the definition (or use depending on how one sees it) of `yearly_sums`.

You are definining it as a tuple and looping over it:

```
yearly_sums = key, sum(value)
```

So the first iteration of `for item in yearly_sums:` gives you the year and as a result, `Yearly sum is: Year1` is printed. The second returns the actual costs and you get the result you need.

---

Instead, you can use the following:

```
d = {'year1':[1,2], 'year2':[3,4], 'year3':[5,6], 'year4':[7,8], 'year5':[9,10], 'year6':[11,12], 'year7':[13,14]}

for year, costs in d.items():
    print('Yearly sum for {} is: {}'.format(year, sum(costs)))
```

Which prduces:

```
Yearly sum for year1 is: 3
Yearly sum for year2 is: 7
Yearly sum for year3 is: 11
Yearly sum for year4 is: 15
Yearly sum for year5 is: 19
Yearly sum for year6 is: 23
Yearly sum for year7 is: 27
```

---

**Alternatively**, to keep your code as much as possible:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    yearly_sums = key, sum(value)
    print('Yearly sum for {} is: {}'.format(*yearly_sums))
```

which of course produces the same output as above.

Comment: Your code works. However, since I had to calculate the total sum of the monthly expenditures, the only proper option is to define a tuple/list where I can loop over it to calculate the final sum.

Comment: @Shiv_90 No it is not. And even though simplifying your problem before posting it on SO generally helps a lot, you might overdo it and end up posting something entirely different which seems to be the case here. So, ask the question you have. Not a different one.

Comment: Good point. But from here I'll proceed on my own. Being fairly new to Python, I wanted to have the clarification as to why a tuple would print out such results. The plan was that I print out the numerics like you showed and then proceed after getting the clarity (after all thats how nice programs are built). But the prints prevented me from looping it further because of the dual results (I need a single `item` to calculate a total). This will also help me in the future when looping over tuples to print exact values.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    yearly_sums = key, sum(value)
    print('Yearly sum is:', yearly_sums[1])

Yearly sum is: 3
Yearly sum is: 7
Yearly sum is: 11
Yearly sum is: 15
Yearly sum is: 19
Yearly sum is: 23
Yearly sum is: 27
```

I hope this helps.